# How to compare values of corresponding cells in multiple named column ranges and change interior color in another corresponding cell

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I want to write a code in Excel VBA that compares the values in corresponding cells in 3 named ranges (say, "Peter", "Paul" & "John"), and if all three values are >= 3, then the interior color of the corresponding cell in a fourth named range say, "James", is changed to Green. I wrote the code using offset but the code doesn't work properly if I insert new columns in-between "Peter", "Paul" and "John". Please can you help me write a code that uses named ranges, to avoid an error when new columns are added?
Thank you.

```
If Cell.Value >= 3 Then
            If Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value >= 3 Then
                If Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value >= 3 Then
                    If Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value >= 3 Then
                        Cell.Offset(0, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
```

Comment: You should probably use `AND` to make it one-line check rather than nesting so many `If` statements e.g. `If Cell.Offset(0,1).Value >=3 AND Cell.Offset(0,2).Value >=3 AND...` etc. Logically it ends up the same but it'd be neater.

Comment: @jamheadart - it's not exactly the same... a one-liner means would mean all the conditions would be evaluated.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. I want all conditions to be evaluated for each cell. My problem is how to avoid using offset. I want to refer to the named ranges directly to ensure my code is not affected if the column number changes when I insert new columns.

Comment: @BigBen does VBA not short-circuit if any of the AND conditions fail? Why not!?

Comment: @jamheadart - it does not short-circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
Dim xCel As Range, rPtr As Long
Dim xSht As Worksheet

Set xSht = ActiveSheet
rPtr = 0
For Each xCel In xSht.Range("Peter").Cells
   rPtr = rPtr + 1
   If xCel.Value >= 3 Then
      If xSht.Range("Paul").Cells(rPtr, 1).Value >= 3 Then
         If xSht.Range("John").Cells(rPtr, 1).Value >= 3 Then
            xSht.Range("James").Cells(rPtr, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 34
         End If
      End If
   End If
Next xCel
```

This solves the problem you mentioned, but it still presumes all ranges are the same length and single column